# R Shiny DataTable: Identify Displayed Rows

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I'm working on an R Shiny App containing a DataTable (`myDataTable`). There I need three export functions, providing the following functionality:

1. export *all* the rows to CSV
2. export the *selected* rows to CSV
3. export the *displayed* rows to CSV

One and two are easily solved. 1. All entries: I just export the server-side `data.frame` that serves as the data model for the DataTable. 2. Selected entries: I access selected rows like this:

```
observeEvent(input$myDataTable_rows_selected, {
    rows <- sort(input$myDataTable_rows_selected)
    # do something with rows
}
```

But how can I find out which rows are *displayed* (i.e. filtered)? I thought of an HTML approach, where I select all the `tr` elements that are childs of `div#myDataTable`, but `shinyjs` doesn't offer any useful functions for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `input$myDataTable_rows_all` for the filtered data.

Small example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput('myDataTable')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {    
    observeEvent(input$myDataTable_rows_all, {
      rows_filtered <- input$myDataTable_rows_all
      rows_displayed <- rows_filtered[1:min(length(rows_filtered), input$myDataTable_state$length)]
      # Download rows with your download fct.
      print(rows_displayed)
    })

    output$myDataTable = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(mtcars, options = list(stateSave = TRUE))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `_rows_all` contains only the _filtered_ rows and not _all_ rows. But there's still the difference between _displayed_ and _filtered_ rows (the table has a number of rows displayed). So I think the user of my app has to be instructed in that way.

Comment: ah ok, i get it know. Well, thats possible with the state variable where you can see how much rows are displayed. I am not sure i make it in the next minutes, then i edit in the evening,...

Comment: No hurry, I only will be working on it in 11 or 12 hours ;-)

Comment: oh my new commnt wasnt posted. Actually i already posted the update 3 hours ago :) See the edit.

Comment: Now it works, thanks! I didn't see the `stateSave` option.